# Replacing multiple encoding of html5 video javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have an html5 video that I would like to automatically update with a new video source as the previous video finishes.

My video code is as follows:

```
        <video autoplay preload loop controls id="v"> 
        <source src="videos/DP.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'> 
        <source src="videos/DP.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'> 
        <source src="videos/DP.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'> 
    </video>
```

I can use *video.src* to update the source, but how do I modify the source to include the 3 different encodings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you give the `<source>` tags an ID and then reference them?

```
<source src="" type="" id="mp4">
```

JavaScript

```
(function() {
    var mp4 = document.getElementById('mp4');
    mp4.src = 'newFile.mp4';
})();
```

Comment: Thank you! This seemed to work fine in all browsers (that I care about)